# Snackbar <merge> error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-snackbar

I' m trying to show snackbar in my activity but the InflateException constantly beats me up. In earlier stages of my project I can make it work, later; I add fragments to my activity and I get InflateException since then.

The code:

```
Snackbar.Make(DrawerLayout, "Message", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
```

`DrawerLayout` is root view of my activity as shown below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ToolbarLayout">
            <include
                layout="@layout/Toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ContentFrame"
            android:layout_below="@id/ToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/LeftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Note that** I don't know if it's related but `ContentFrame` and `LeftDrawer` are Fragment placeholders

The exception string I get:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true ---> Android.Views.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00082] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12649 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/JNIEnv.g.cs:562 
  at Android.Support.Design.Widget.Snackbar.Make (Android.Views.View view, Java.Lang.ICharSequence text, System.Int32 duration) [0x00078] in <0d997552ddad494094d94e2a353b2022>:0 
  at Android.Support.Design.Widget.Snackbar.Make (Android.Views.View view, System.String text, System.Int32 duration) [0x00013] in <0d997552ddad494094d94e2a353b2022>:0 
  at FC.Android.Infrastructure.Activities.MainActivity.NavDrawer_NavigationItemSelected (System.Object sender, Android.Views.IMenuItem e) [0x00029] in E:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FC\FC.Android\Infrastructure\Activities\MainActivity.cs:73 
  --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:188)
    at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:215)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
    ... 14 more
```

**I check the followings:**

1. Activity theme is inherited from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
2. Tried `Window.DecorView.RootView` and `FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content)` instead of `DrawerLayout` it doesn't work

**Edit:**
I discovered something strange: If I run the app with Debug I get the error, If run the app normally (without attached debugger) snackbars works just fine.

Comment: It happened for me after updating support library to 27.1.0. Apparently, merged-not-compiled-resources directory has the wrong version of design_layout_snackbar_include.xml which started by <merge tag! Can you confirm this is the same case?

Answer (score 0):

Make it shown on `ContentFrame` not on `Drawerlayout`

```
Snackbar.Make(contentFrame, "Message", Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
```

and don't forget to firstly bind the view `ContentFrame` to the variable `contentFrame`

[Snakbar make](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Well, It works when debugger is not attached, it's weird isn't it?

Comment: it is so weird !, you can always post a new question

Comment: @sinanyil plz accept the answer if it solved the question's problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply but It doesn't solve my problem. Actually problem doesn't solved yet. Nevertheless now I know when it's happens and it's not.

Comment: You have two separate problems, this question problem is solved by answer as you said ! and as I said you can post a new question for your new problem.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here; the comment I wrote yesterday wasn't related to your solution. I was discovered one of the reasons for the problem and shared with you. And I edited my question according to new update.